# How to change a function based views to class based view?

Tags: django, view, django-class-based-views

I have this function based view but i want to create a class based view basing on this code. I am new to Django plase someone help me

```
def contact(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    cform = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if cform.is_valid():
        name = request.POST.get('name','')
        gender = cform.cleaned_data.get('gender','')
        email = request.POST.get('email','')
        mobile = request.POST.get('mobile','')
        about = request.POST.get('about','')
    data = ContactData(
            name = name,
            gender = gender,
            email = email,
            mobile = mobile,
            about = about
        )
    data.save()
    cform = ContactForm()
    return render(request,'contact.html', {'cform':cform})
else:
    cform = ContactForm(request.POST)
    return render(request,'contact.html',{'cform':cform})
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the forms?

Comment: Are you talking about a bootstrap feature not working or the lines of code not working?

Comment: Check if bootstrap is loading in your dev console.